# Remark or Rehype Plugin to convert newlines(\n) to </br>

Tags: javascript, markdown, remarkjs, rehype

I have a markdown document and I am using rehype and remark to convert it into html.
The problem am facing is that, inside my markdown file, I have some (`\n`s) which I want to be converted into `<br/>` tags in HTML but I do not know how to do it.
Also, there is no plugin which solves this problem.

Comment: The conversion of `\n` to `<br>` is the default behaviour? https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-rehype

Comment: No, I want to know how to do it

Comment: Yes, that's what I understand https://codesandbox.io/s/3s3g0?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @evolutionxbox. It only converts 1 \n to break but does not convert the rest

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. The one I gave converts all of them.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am using [mdsvex](https://mdsvex.pngwn.io/) to import the rehype and remark plugins.

Comment: This is the configurations
```import remark_slug from 'remark-slug';
import remark_emoji from 'remark-emoji';
import remark_attr from 'remark-attr';
import remark_breaks from "remark-breaks";

import rehype_toc from 'rehype-toc';

const settings = {
 extension: '.md',
 rehypePlugins: [rehype_toc],
 remarkPlugins: [[remark_attr, { scope: 'every' }], remark_slug, remark_emoji, remark_breaks]
};

export default settings;
```

Comment: That's not an example. Please may you read the link "[mcve]" and provide one so that we can help you?

Comment: @Lucretius the box you provided is not correct. OP wants to convert `\n` to `<br />` but the html output from the markdown is `h1 + p` rather than `h1 + br + p`

Answer (score 0):

`remark-rehype` won't convert newline to `<br />`. It only convert to:

```json
{
    "type": "text",
    "value": "\n",
    "position": {
        "start": {
            "line": 1,
            "column": 65,
            "offset": 64
        },
        "end": {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 1,
            "offset": 65
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to convert `\n` to `<br />`, you need to modify the tree by replacing `\n` to `<br />` in `text` node using `visit`.

```bash
npm install remark remark-html unist-util-visit
```

```js
const remark = require('remark');
const remark2rehype = require('remark-rehype');
const unified = require('unified');
const rehypeStringify = require('rehype-stringify');
const visit = require('unist-util-visit');
const u = require('unist-builder');

// Custom plugin to convert newlines in text to `br` element nodes
const remarkNewlinesToBrs = () => tree => {
  visit(tree, 'text', (node, index, parent) => {
    if (node.value.includes('\n')) {
      // Split the text at newlines
      const parts = node.value.split('\n');
      const newNodes = [];
      parts.forEach((part, i) => {
        if (part !== '') {
          // Add text node for the non-empty part
          newNodes.push(u('text', part));
        }
        if (i !== parts.length - 1) {
          // Add a `br` element node for each newline, except after the last part
          newNodes.push(u('element', {tagName: 'br'}, []));
        }
      });
      // Replace the current text node with the new nodes
      parent.children.splice(index, 1, ...newNodes);
    }
  });
};

// Example Markdown
const markdown = 'This is a test.\nThis should be on a new line.';

// Process the Markdown
unified()
  .use(remark)
  .use(remarkNewlinesToBrs) // Use the custom plugin
  .use(remark2rehype, {allowDangerousHtml: true})
  .use(rehypeStringify)
  .process(markdown, (err, file) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(String(file));
  });
```